How Do I properly get the correct description of an image using gradio_client? and LLaVa?
Describe the issue
Issue:
I'm trying to use the gradio_client python library to run LLaVa
Command:
from gradio_client import Client, file
imagePath = ""# a path to an image on your computer, or a url to an image
client = Client("https://llava.hliu.cc/")
job = client.submit("what image is this, file(imagePath), "Crop", api_name="/add_text")

return(job.result())# it returns a tuple, instead of a byte, string 

Log/output:
([['<img src=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" alt="user upload image" />what image is this', None]], '', None)                                     

I had to reduce the output, because it is too large.
How I tried to fix the issue:
I used this function
import base64
def encodeImage(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')

then I tried to decode the image using the above function before submitting it to gradio, but it didn't work
after that, I did this:
def decodeBytes(byte_data):
    return base64.b64decode(byte_data).decode('utf-8')

This function in the other hand, is being called after gradio's request, but I got an error like this:
  File "C:\Users\kefas\python programs\gradio.py", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                      
    decoded_result = base64.b64decode(job.result()).decode('utf-8')                                                                                                         
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\base64.py", line 80, in b64decode                                                                                                    
    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)                                                                                                                                          
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\base64.py", line 45, in _bytes_from_decode_data                                                                                      
    raise TypeError("argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII "                                                                                                      
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'tuple'

What can I do?
